# Can't change website url, VS2013 on win8.1

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2013, iis-8

I'm trying to change IIS express and Website URL to point to a custom URL so i can try the website from my mobile. The point is, **the changes I made (read below) don't change the website starting url.**

I already changed the part at the IIS Express **applicationhost.config** file, from **port:localhost** to a **port:custom name**, tried to change the part at the **.sln** file where it points to the localhost.

I uploaded a screenshot from my project's property page, I can't find **Use Custom Server** option under Server or the **Use Local IIS Web Server** option.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Right-click on your `Web Site` in Solution Explorer and select `Convert to web application` and then you can find the options you need under Properties -> Web

Comment: Converting had to be done manually, as web site didn't had the convert to web application option. After that, I had the Local IIS option available. Thanks

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware that the option is removed. I still use VS2012